# Is there a way to accumulate from right to left in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools, accumulate

Python already has an `itertools.accumulate` function. However, this function accumulates from left to right:

```py
>>> list(itertools.accumulate([[x] for x in range(5)]))
[[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Instead of that, I would like to accumulate from right to left, like so:

```py
>>> list(accumulate_from_right([[x] for x in range(5)]))
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4], [4]]
```

My current solution (which is only applicable to lists) is very inefficient and ugly:

```py
>>> list(x[::-1] for x in accumulate([y] for y in reversed(range(5))))[::-1]
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4], [4]]
```

**What is the best way to accumulate a list from right to left?**

**Edit: I'm using a range just as an example. I would like to be able to apply this method with any nested list.**

Here's another example that doesn't use range:

```py
>>> list(accumulate_from_right(['a', 'b', 'c']))
['abc', 'bc', 'c']
```

Comment: Is this question about `accumulate` in particular, or just how to get the list of "descending" suffixes?

Comment: `print(list(itertools.accumulate([[x] for x in range(5, 0, -1)]))[::-1])` ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed some more examples so that it becomes clear in what way you want this to be generalized.

Comment: @chepner Sorry! I misunderstood what you meant by "descending" suffixes. I want the function to be able to apply this method to any list!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to make a single pass over the input of `accumulate_from_right`:

```
def accumulate_from_right(vals):
   return [vals[i:] for i in range(len(vals))]

print(accumulate_from_right(list(range(5))))
print(accumulate_from_right(['a', 'b', 'c']))
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4], [4]]
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c'], ['c']]
```

Comment: That's pretty clever, but is there a way to generalize that method? I only used the range as an example.

Comment: @PradhyumR that should generalise fine - just substitute your list in for `range(5)` :)

Comment: @Tim Ajax1234's method uses pattern-matching and a range to create the desired output. It won't generalize well to strings (which is what I'm using this for).

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

```
[list(range(i, 5)) for i in range(5)]
```

returns

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4], [4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it easy to use the itertools accumulate and use [::-1] at the result to reverse?

```
list(itertools.accumulate([[x] for x in range(5)]))[::-1]
```

Comment: No, the actual content of the list would be different